# Xcode static libraries error "file is not of required architecture"

Tags: iphone

I'm attempted to add an open source project to my iphone project and added the source files and the libraries to my project folder and referenced them inside of my project. However, when I try to build the project the linked static libraries are giving me a warning:

> file is not of required architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator libraries and the iPhoneOS libraries are built seperately. If you are building for the device ID, make sure under your target the .framework file is the iPhoneOS version, similarly if you are building on the simulator, make sure it is the simulator version.